# How can I calculate this expected value

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, quantum-computer

I know this is a simple questions but I'm having trouble with this. I have this wave function [image]

and I'm trying to calculate the expected value of QS, where Q and S are the operators
[image]

Here we have a two qubits system and the operators with subindexes 1 and 2 act on first and second qubit, respectively. X,Y and Z are the Pauli matrices on the x,y and z axis. For example, $Y_2$ is the operator $\sigma_y$ acting on the second qubit .
I'm trying this:
$$
<QS>=<\psi|QS|\psi>=\left(\cfrac{<01|-<10|}{\sqrt{2}}\right)Z_{1}\left(\cfrac{-Z_{2}-X_{2}}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\left(\cfrac{|01>-|10>}{\sqrt{2}}\right)=\cfrac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\left(<01|-<10|\right)Z_{1}(-Z_{2}-X_{2})\left(|01>-|10>\right)
$$

I'm not sure about this, but I think with the definition I've given, $X_2$ acts in this way on $|\psi>$
$X_{2}|\psi>=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 1\\
1 & 0
\end{array}\right)\left(\cfrac{|01>-|10>}{\sqrt{2}}\right)=\left(\cfrac{|00>-|11>}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$

and $Z_2$ on $|\psi>$

$Z_{2}|\psi>=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0\\
0 & -1
\end{array}\right)\left(\cfrac{|01>-|10>}{\sqrt{2}}\right)=\left(\cfrac{-|01>-|11>}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$

and
$Z_{1}|\psi>=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0\\
0 & -1
\end{array}\right)\left(\cfrac{|01>-|10>}{\sqrt{2}}\right)=\left(\cfrac{|01>+|11>}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$

but doing this I have a 0 result, and I'm supposed to obtain $\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$

$$
<QS>=\cfrac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\left(<01|-<10|\right)Z_{1}(-Z_{2}-X_{2})\left(|01>-|10>\right)=\cfrac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\left(<01|-<10|\right)Z_{1}(-Z_{2})\left(-|00>+|11>\right)=\cfrac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\left(<01|-<10|\right)Z_{1}\left(|00>+|11>\right)=\cfrac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\left(<01|-<10|\right)\left(|00>-|11>\right)=0
$$

Could  someone help me with the calculation?